# How do I cultivate ginger from a piece of root?

Tags: root-vegetables, spices

A month back, I planted a small portion of Ginger root in a pot and watered it moderately every day. Seeing no results so far, today I cleared the pot and saw that Ginger root had started to decompose instead of rooting. I have no idea what went wrong.

- I used fairly fresh Ginger root.
- I kept the soil moist.
- I kept the pot in partial sunlight.

Any suggestions, how do I grow it again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It had to be dry and not fresh (out from soil one or two weeks). Put in plain light but not in sun, nor partial.

In a clay pot, wide and deep, typically from 5-10 liters, with this root in the center and in depth, taking care to cover it with universal soil.

The watering must be regular and especially whenever the soil is dry, but avoiding stagnation of water in the saucer that would lead to the emergence of fungal plant diseases known as root rot.

That, if you are sure that your ginger was healthy. Maybe it was not.

EDIT @ (just learned how answering to comments)
Rhizomes have to be very dry.
It works like the cuttings of succulents. When you divide the rhizomes of ginger, one part is "wound", ie open to infections. As with cacti, you have to wait several days before burying. The "wound" has to dry thoroughly.

Likewise, the rhizome of the ginger, which is fleshy, has to dry for some weeks before to be buryed. Even better, like cacti, put it in the ground and wait at least a few days before watering.

Comment: got related doubt, why it is required to be dry? I was thinking that fresh will work better because it is fresh.

Comment: It works like the cuttings of succulents. When you divide the rhizomes of ginger, one part is "wound", ie open to infections.
As with cacti, you have to wait several days before burying. The "wound" has to dry thoroughly. Likewise, the rhizome of the ginger, which is fleshy, has to dry for some weeks. Even better, like cacti, put it in the ground and wait at least a few days before watering.

Answer (score 4):

We had great success growing ginger offsets with just a bowl of water.  We took a fresh ginger and put it in a small bowl with a half inch ( one cm) of water that we kept topped up.  Only one end of the root was in the bowl. We left it like that for four or five weeks and roots and, eventually leaves, sprouted from a small area at the side.  After six weeks we cut it off and left the parent in the bowl.  It proceeded to grow another offset.

The offsets had roots and leaves so we just potted them up and they are one foot (30 cm) tall now after twelve weeks.